# Indexes on columns - Two separated index VS One group index?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have a query like this:

```
select sum(col1) from table where col2 = 'X' and col3 = 'Y';
```

Now I want to know, Which one is better?

Separated indexes:

```
  KEY `col2` (`col2`),
  KEY `col3` (`col3`)
```

Group indexes:

```
  KEY `both` (`col2`,`col3`)
```

Also I want to know, `col1` needs to index?

Comment: It would be quicker to test than to ask

Comment: @Strawberry So there is not any specific rule?

Comment: I think you can determine (some of) them through testing - but the answer below elegantly encapsulates two key points

Comment: A better index would be  KEY `somename` (`col2`,`col3`,`col1`)

This is called a covering index,the query doesnt need to touch the table.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok well, just one question. `where col1 = 'X'` can use of this: `KEY name (col1, col2)`? Or that needs to a single index?

Comment: @Mihai Sounds good, Ok thanks.

Comment: Col1 can - because it's the first column in the index, but col2 cannot. It would be like trying to look up a word in a dictionary when you knew everything except the first letter

Comment: If it starts with the left column in the index, it can use a compound index.And a compound index can only be fully used by condition with AND.That\`s why it doesnt really matter if it\`s col2,col3 or col3,col2 for your query.

Comment: @Strawberry Curiouser and curiouser...! I think you are wrong, because in this case `col1` and `col2` are exactly in the same position. is it not? Can you please read this again: *"`where col1 = 'X'` can use of this: `KEY name (col1, col2)`? Or that needs to a single index?"*

Comment: @Mihai What do you mean of *"left column"*?

Comment: the column with which the index starts'

Comment: I'm not wrong padiwan. Col2,col1 is not the same as col1,col2. However, 'WHERE col1=x AND col2=y' is the same as 'WHERE col2=y AND col1=x'

Comment: @Strawberry ow!! alright then. So `key name col2, col1` is fine for `where col2 = 'x'` but it is not fine for `where col1 = 'x'`. Correct?

Comment: @Mihai What you said is really interesting for me and I learned a new thing today. Thanks. Just how it works for three columns? `key name col1, col2, col3` is usable just for `where col1 = x` ? *(I want to know a compound index can be usable for which single queries)*

Comment: YEs,exactly.If your WHERE starts with either col2 or col3 the index wont be used.I suggest downloading a sample db like Sakila database and import it locally.You would learn to import data into mysql also and run queries on it with EXPLAIN.

Comment: I think we've covered this

Comment: @Mihai I got it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mihai Really sorry for asking again, I promise this is the lase ;-)! Well, I want to know. is this index `key name (col1, col2, col3)` useful for this query `where col1='x' and col2='y'` ?

Comment: Yes it will be used as long as the permutations of columns with AND condition match the index column order.So `where col1='x' and col2='y'` and `where col2='x' and col1='y'` both will use the index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where col2 = 'X' and col3 = 'Y';
```

This WHERE dictates the use of the compound index:

```
KEY `both` (`col2`,`col3`)
```

col1 does not need to be indexed since you are not WHEREing on it.

Note: if you also have other queries that do WHERE on col3 without col2, the answer may be different..